# Evaluate $ \lim n \left[ 1-\frac{(n+1)^n}{en^n}\right] $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate the following limit of sequence

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} n \left[ 1-\frac{(n+1)^n}{en^n}\right] $$

I've transformed it in a 0/0 inequality and tried to apply L'Hospital one time, but the function seems even more complicated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the limit going to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since (as long as $n\to +\infty$):
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \exp\left(n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\exp\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) $$
we have:
$$1-\frac{1}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=1-\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
hence:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} n\cdot\left[1-\frac{1}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]=\frac{1}{2}.$$
We just used the Taylor series of $\log(1+z)$ and $e^z$ around $z=0$.

Answer (score 2):

We have using Taylor series

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\exp\left(n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right)\sim_\infty\exp\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)\sim_\infty e\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)$$
so we see easily that the desired limit is $\frac12$.

Answer (score -1):

Use the fact that $lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} (1+1/n)^n = e$ to get limit of your sequence equal to $1-1/e^2$

Comment: I didnt get your suggestion. I only see an indetermination

Comment: (-1) The limit equals $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I got this one too but everyone else says it's. $\frac{1}{2}$